# Java Reflection Setter

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to set the values of class member variable by using java reflection but during invocation of method it will stop and it doesn't throw any exception or error . It's irritating I am stuck here plz help me....................
Here is my code

```
public class SMapper {

    public void SetMapforvalues(Hashtable obj) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {

        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {

            String fieldName = field.getName();
            Object value = obj.get(fieldName);

            if (value != null) {

                Class<?> type = field.getClass();

                if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
                    Integer data = (Integer)value;
                    field.set(this, data);       

                } else if (type.equals(String.class)) {
                    String data = (String)value;                    
                    field.set(this, data);
                } else if (type.equals(Double.class)) {
                    Double data = (Double) value;
                    field.set(this, data);       
                } else {

                    Method method = type.getMethod("SetMapforvalues");
                    Object methodreturn = method.invoke(value, obj);                  

                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Use Spring's ReflectionUtils.doWithFields() method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

You're getting the declared fields of your `SMapper` class which I suspect is not what you want to do.  That class has no declared fields so the array is empty and your for loop is never entered.

Comment: getDeclaredFields doesn't give you any fields for a super class.

Comment: Actually i am calling this function from another class X object which is inherited from SMapper so it will get the fields of X class but after completion of loop it is not going for invoking the method for Y class object which is declared in X class  and X and Y both are inherited from SMapper.

Answer (score 0):

If this method is called, it should either work (and if it has no fields  in the class as @MrWiggles points out it won't do anything), or produce an error which you might be ignoring.

The best way to tell is to step through your code in your debugger, or you can try to trap all and print it somewhere you will see it.

i.e.

```
public void SetMapforvalues(Hashtable obj) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    try {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fields));
        // your code here
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```